# Is there a way to integrate $\oint \frac{dz}{z^{i}}$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I was wondering if there is some trick to integrate a contour integral of the form $$ \oint \frac{dz}{2 \pi i } \frac{1}{z^{i}} $$ If the imaginary exponent $i$ wasn't there, I would just use Cauchy's integral formula and get $1$. Is it possible to integrate the above?

Comment: We need (i) the definition of the contour marked with a $\circ$  and (ii) the intended meaning of $z^i$.

Comment: Integration is just some circle around the origin, say. I'm asking this question because I came across this integral in my work on string theory. But it is possible that it's just not integrable. I was just wondering.

Comment: The result will depend of the chosen branch.

Answer (score 3):

If the circuit is $|z| = R > 0$, then $z = Re^{i\theta}$, $dz = Rie^{i\theta}d\theta$  and
$$
\oint\frac{dz}{z^{i}} =
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{Rie^{i\theta}}{(Re^{i\theta})^i}d\theta =
\frac{Ri}{R^i}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{i\theta}}{e^{-\theta}}d\theta =
\frac{Ri}{R^i}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i\theta+\theta}d\theta = \cdots
$$

Comment: Using the "principal value" for the power, we have $(e^{i\theta})^i = e^{-\theta}$ for $0 < \theta < \pi$ but not for $\pi < \theta < 2\pi$.

Comment: @GEdgar, true, as I said in the comment to the question... and forgot here.

Comment: @GEdgar, edited.